# Elasticsearch has primary shard is not active, returns org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a problem when writing data into Elasticsearch. I am running ES in by Kubernetes with configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: local-path
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: es-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: es
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: es
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: elasticsearch-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: elasticsearch-pvc
      containers:
        - name: es
          image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: es-port
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              value: single-node
            - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
              value: "true"
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elasticsearch-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

While indexing document, the process suddenly stopped and the log was produced like this:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-06-14T08:51:55,733Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "es-deployment-cb655db9-5rjt8", "message": "path: /test_studies_202106/_doc/08eb2832-c93f-405f-bf8d-2f273b79ba4a, params: {refresh=true, index=test_studies_202106, id=08eb2832-c93f-405f-bf8d-2f273b79ba4a}", "cluster.uuid": "KaQIvU0rRUeTcCEGItKh4Q", "node.id": "Lyg8XMQwRV239s0RKTymew" ,
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [test_studies_202106][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest [[test_studies_202106][0]] containing [index {[test_studies_202106][_doc][08eb2832-c93f-405f-bf8d-2f273b79ba4a], source[{\"status\":\"UNASSIGNED\",\"project_id\":\"760461bd-2356-4e10-8a5a-ea158607d784\",\"creator_id\":\"6390c1df-3886-47b5-8276-f110a46ca2af\",\"id\":\"08eb2832-c93f-405f-bf8d-2f273b79ba4a\",\"time_inserted\":1623660655731,\"dicom_tags\":{\"StudyDate\":[\"19700101\"],\"StudyTime\":[\"100000\"],\"AccessionNumber\":[\"2affa434-3a8d-4791-81a4-21c8ea1b78bd\"],\"ReferringPhysicianName\":[\"80cd24f9-2b9b-456d-96b4-bde2b45f8491\"],\"StudyInstanceUID\":[\"1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.7.112561.30000020062214142441900007170\"],\"Modality\":[\"CT\"],\"SeriesInstanceUID\":[\"1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.7.112561.30000020062405350262300000199\"],\"SeriesNumber\":[\"2\"],\"SOPInstanceUID\":[\"1.3.12.2.1107.5.1.7.112561.30000020062405350262300000413\"],\"PatientAge\":[\"084Y\"],\"PatientName\":[\"b43eff53-e2a2-4dec-87cd-1e4f6fa61070\"],\"PatientID\":[\"953855d1-e458-4025-9d80-8d23e3ea5d29\"],\"PatientSex\":[\"\"],\"BodyPartExamined\":[\"ABDOMEN\"]},\"code\":\"L-49\"}]}] and a refresh]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportReplicationAction.java:898) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:743) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$ReroutePhase$2.onTimeout(TransportReplicationAction.java:858) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:325) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:605) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:678) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
```

I've checked `localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain`, it returns:

```
{"test_studies_202106":{"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1623658188474","number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"aZqhlv9TQ5umHeTszxPNIQ","version":{"created":"7090299"},"provided_name":"test_studies_202106"}}}}
```

Then I called the API: `http://localhost:9200/_cluster/allocation/explain`:

```
{
  "index": "test_studies_202106",
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": true,
  "current_state": "unassigned",
  "unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
    "at": "2021-06-14T09:09:41.196Z",
    "last_allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
  },
  "can_allocate": "no_valid_shard_copy",
  "allocate_explanation": "cannot allocate because all found copies of the shard are either stale or corrupt",
  "node_allocation_decisions": [
    {
      "node_id": "Lyg8XMQwRV239s0RKTymew",
      "node_name": "es-deployment-cb655db9-5rjt8",
      "transport_address": "10.42.0.201:9300",
      "node_attributes": {
        "ml.machine_memory": "33608118272",
        "xpack.installed": "true",
        "transform.node": "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs": "20"
      },
      "node_decision": "no",
      "store": {
        "in_sync": true,
        "allocation_id": "oEyow8RmSYeRT4ky00NVBw",
        "store_exception": {
          "type": "corrupt_index_exception",
          "reason": "failed engine (reason: [merge failed]) (resource=preexisting_corruption)",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "i_o_exception",
            "reason": "failed engine (reason: [merge failed])",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "corrupt_index_exception",
              "reason": "checksum failed (hardware problem?) : expected=edc83af3 actual=29c90a2a (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path=\"/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/aZqhlv9TQ5umHeTszxPNIQ/0/index/_14u.fdt\")))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I was looking for a solution in https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/elasticsearch-unassigned-shards/#pinpointing-problematic-shards, but it seems like I missed something. I tried to delete the index then write data into it again, but the writing progress is stopped after about 800 requests. Please help!

Comment: did you change watermark settings? merge problem is due to disk problem. maybe lack of free space or bad block.

Comment: @hamidbayat: I've checked the disk usage, there are many storage in my machine. About the watermark settings, how can I change it?

Comment: run checkdisk on your storage. (due to checksum failed (hardware problem?))

Comment: @hamidbayat: i've checked, my disk is ok